# EditText isn't saved by SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm supposed to save three EditTexts' strings using `SharedPreferences` so I can use them in a TextView when user re-enter the app. This is what I have tried:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText PrivName;
    private EditText LastName;
    private EditText LastMov;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    private Button SaveBtn;
    private TextView Text;
    String Priv, Lst, Mov;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PrivName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.PrivName);
        LastName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LastName);
        LastMov = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LastMov);
        SaveBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SaveBtn);
        Text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Message);

        sp = getSharedPreferences("Movies", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SaveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Priv = PrivName.getText().toString();
                Lst = LastName.getText().toString();
                Mov = LastMov.getText().toString();

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

                editor.putString("Name", Priv);
                editor.putString("Name2", Lst);
                editor.putString("Movie", Mov);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });
        Text.setText("We hope that you  " + Priv + " "  +Lst + " enjoyed the movie: " + Mov);
    }
}
```

Obviously the problem is that when you click the button the TextView changes to what you want but when you re-enter the app everything resets instead of staying the same

Comment: I see here that you only save the text in ShredPrefs. When do you read from it to fill the text after the aoo relaunched?

Comment: @Keselme The problem is im struggling to save the text. I want a button to save what's written in the EditText views using SharedPrefs and then for it to show in a TextView and stay the same even if you restart the app (it resets at the moment)

Comment: Did you try to open the Shared Preferences file after saving, was it empty?

Answer (score 0):

You need to also read from the SharedPrefs, so you can actually fill the EditText.
Try something like that:

Add this in your onCreate method

```
sp = getSharedPreferences("Movies", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
PrivName.setText(sp.getString("Name", "")); //The empty string after the comma is a default value incase you don't a stored value for that key
LastName.setText(sp.getString("Name2", ""));
LastMov.setText(sp.getString("Movie", ""));
```

Comment: It keeps whats written in the EditText views now which is better but the TextView that im trying to use to display the Strings resets when you reopen the app

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the following method at the end of your **onCreate** method.

```
private void showSavedValue()
{
  // Retaining the values from shared preferences
  String savedPrivName = sp.getString("Name",""); // If no value was stored previously it will return an empty string
  String savedLastName = sp.getString("Name2", "");
  String savedLastMovie = sp.getString("Movie","");

  //Write your code here to use these values where you want to use them


}
```

Note : Try to follow the recommended naming convention while writing Java. A detailed guide on Java naming conventions can be found [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Look at your source code properly what you are doing..

```
editor.putString("Name", Priv);
editor.putString("Name2", Lst);
editor.putString("Movie", Mov);
editor.commit();
```

Here you are saving some parameter.. Where `"Name"` is a id and, you are saving `Priv` strings to that id.. Same is happening to Name2 and Movie.

```
Priv = PrivName.getText().toString();
Lst = LastName.getText().toString();
Mov = LastMov.getText().toString();
```

You are getting texts from  Edittexts and saving them to `Priv,Lst,Mov`. But, they aren't working as sharedPreferences. That means when you restart the application these values will be gone...

```
Text.setText("We hope that you  " + Priv + " "  +Lst + " enjoyed the movie: " + Mov);
```

In the above source code you are showing those values which will be gone if you restart. And, you wrote that code to onCreate method. So, when you are starting application these values are showing but, which has no value(`null`).

Here what you should try.. [@Niaz Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8889580/niaz-ahmed)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66992629/13146129) is correct but, his explanation is very poor that's why I am posting another answer.

```
String savedPrivName = sp.getString("Name",""); // If no value was stored previously it will return an empty string


String savedLastName = sp.getString("Name2", "");
  String savedLastMovie = sp.getString("Movie","");

Text.setText("We hope that you  " + savedPrivName + " "  +savedLastName + " enjoyed the movie: " + savedLastMovie);
```